# Can we predict the rising temperature of Earth?

Tags: climate-change, sun, human-influence, geomagnetism

Where can I find a model of Earth's past climates and future projections from combined possibilities like magnetic pole movement and other forms of global warming as a map? Without a reference it has been said that enough heat could trigger a mini ice age.

At what temperature change would people have to migrate towards or away from the equator?

[What happens when the North and South poles flip?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/17110/what-happens-when-the-north-and-south-poles-flip)

Comment: i think the part of your question about magnetic pole movement and global warming must be a misunderstanding,the magnetic field of earth does not change the temparature on earth(in the van allen belts and in the magnetosphere yes but not in the air and ground of earth)

Comment: Start here: https://history.aip.org/climate/index.htm