# Strength of Magnetic Field at Mid Point of a Reversal

Tags: geology, reversals, planets

As the duration of a magnetic reversal can be up to 12,000 years, could there come a time mid-way in the transition when Earth's magnetic field is as negligible as that of Mars or Venus? Magnetic reversals are random, but we haven't had one for nearly a million years, while the average interval is about 300,000 years.

Comment: this is related https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/17110/what-happens-when-the-north-and-south-poles-flip/17114#17114 you might find some of the links in my answer useful.

Comment: relevent https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=UwQQOYMWR7YC&oi=fnd&pg=PA120&dq=magnetic+field+reversal&ots=4DRF09dK_w&sig=cU6gDPCxK0YGF7f2OJMkbqP05A8#v=onepage&q=magnetic%20field%20reversal&f=false