# Extinctions and geomagnetic inversions

Tags: geology, paleontology, geomagnetism

The article [Did the Earth’s magnetic field affect our evolution?](https://pledgetimes.com/did-the-earths-magnetic-field-affect-our-evolution/) on Pledge Times cite [this Science paper](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/371/6531/811.abstract) to assert:

> These authors speculate that, in the Pleistocene, large mammals could have reached a natural limit of body size until the arrival of Laschamps, when the probability of cell mutation would increase at times of high ultraviolet ray flux. It would not be a catastrophic, instantaneous extinction, but rather an accumulation of mutations produced by radiation over multiple generations, over several thousand years, which is the duration of the minimum intensity of the geomagnetic field during geomagnetic inversions.

My question is: Is there any study correlating other geomagnetic inversions with extinctions in fauna?

---

**Alan Cooper et al(2021)**: "A global environmental crisis 42,000 years ago." *Science*  19 Feb 2021. Vol. 371, Issue 6531, pp. 811-818

Comment: related https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/17110/what-happens-when-the-north-and-south-poles-flip

Comment: The paper goes a long way speculating. No direct evidence on the northern hemisphere connects Laschamps excursion (or any precursory phase, or any geomagnetic excursion in earth's history at all) to an extinction, and the climate record is actually quite good.

Comment: @Mark that question is specific for dinosaurs extinction while mine ask for any extinction

Comment: @Universal_learner, the question may be specific, but the answers aren't.

Comment: @Mark Ok I accept the duplicate. Your answer explain my question