# Safest place on Earth during the pole shift

Tags: meteorology, geomagnetism, poles

Where is the safest place on Earth in relation the magnetic poles as it is moving that will provide the most protection against solar radiation? I imagine the topography may effect the magnetic fields.

Comment: what makes you think that a pole shift involves any danger at all?.the magnetic field of our sun changes every 11 years and this changes the magnetic field of our entire solar system..

Comment: [Why You (Probably) Shouldn't Worry About Earth's Magnetic Poles Flipping](https://www.livescience.com/61603-what-if-magnetic-pole-reversal.html)

Comment: this is related:https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/17110/what-happens-when-the-north-and-south-poles-flip you might find some of the sources i posted there helpful.

Comment: There is so much disinformation these days. Pole reversals happen all the time in earth history, even during human presence and nothing happened. There is one work about a few Kauri trees in New Zealand that claimed without further evidence a reversal had caused environmental damage, but their conclusions are simply wrong.